# 'Rega' in halacha

Tags: time, zemanim

King David uses the word 'Rega' ( moment) in his Tehillim.
Rambam, the Gemara etc. also use the word 'Rega' to describe a moment.

Can we assume that all the previously mentioned speakers are using the term 'Rega' to talk about the same exact length of time?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a great assumption to me. Why would you think to assume that?

Comment: @ Double AA I was wondering if they all stuck to the same exact mathematical length of time when using the word 'Rega'. I do know that they do all mean the same measure when they say 'Kor' or 'Log', for example. Also, if they do mean the same measure of time, I believe I found the length of a 'Rega' using our modern seconds as a reference.

Comment: Do they mean the same thing when they say Kor and Log? Where does David say Log?

Comment: Historically they had accurate measures for weight and volume, but not for time. Time for short things was described as "the amount of time needed to do *x*".

Comment: @N.T. What is inaccurate about such descriptions of time?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't mean it is inaccurate. I mean they did not have what OP called "same exact mathematical length of time."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How much time does His anger last? G-d’s anger lasts a moment. And how long is a moment? One fifty-eight thousand, eight hundred and eighty-eighth of an hour, that is a moment..." ("rega")

(Talmud Brachos, 7a)

The Talmud later on the same page brings a different opinion.

"And how long does His anger last? G-d’s anger lasts a moment. And how long is a moment? Rabbi Avin, and some say Rabbi Avina, said: A moment lasts as long as it takes to say it "rega".

(Talmud Brachos, 7a)

I believe the amount of time it takes to say "rega" is longer than the Gemara's initial calculation of 1/58,888 of an hour.

Interestingly, Tosfos on this Gemara, asks (referring to the Biblical events of Balaam the evil sorcerer and his attempts to curse the Israelites; see Bamidbar Ch. 22-25) upon learning that G-d only gets "angry" for a "rega" moment, "What curse could Balaam have possibly uttered in such a short time?"

Tosfos gives two answers:

1. He could have said "Destroy them!" which in Hebrew is "Kalem".
2. As long as he started his cursing at the right moment, he could continue uttering the full text of his curse even after the "moment" expired.

I point out to my students that the first answer of Tosfos seems to assume that a moment lasts as long as it takes to say "reh-ga", because that is the same time one needs to utter "Kal-em". So an entire curse could be uttered in the time it takes for the passing of that crucial "moment".

Tosfos' second answer assumes the time for a "rega" is according to the first opinion in the Gemara; and when faced with 1/58,888 of an hour, must say that as long as Balaam started his utterance at that sliver of time, he was allowed to continue.

The Gemara sources the word "rega" from:

Tehillim/Psalms 30:6,"כִּ֚י רֶ֥גַע בְּאַפּוֹ֘" "For His wrath lasts but a "moment"..."rega"

and from Yeshaya/Isaiah 26:20 "חֲבִ֥י כִמְעַט־רֶ֖גַע עַד־יַֽעֲבָר זָֽעַם" "...hide for but a moment, ("rega") until the wrath passes."

These are the sources I am aware of that discuss the opinions of the length in time of a Jewish "moment", or "rega".

I hope this helps.

Comment: Rambam Kiddush Hachodesh 10:1

Comment: This number demands an explanation! Why 58,888? (or it's 50000 fifty ribbo plus 8888 right?) WHY!?