# Is there a proper time to curse

Tags: curse, ramchal, mesilas-yesharim

I’m reading the Ramchal, in the book Mesillas Yesharim it says one should not seek revenge etc.  yet there are stories of Tzadik in the Bible who did curse their enemies.

I guess I’m wondering why one should forgive yet some of the sages did curse, like Elijah cursing the men sent to him by calling down fire, or Elisha cursing the men to be killed by bears and cursed Gehazi with leprosy.

Comment: The Gemara Yoma 22B-23A would be an explanation. https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.23a.1?with=all&lang=bi

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/129619/759